# nesting inaide a elif statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm  new on python. I'm  learning it from internet. As we know in the case of short hand if-else we can change a multiline code into just a single line code and it's really awesome!
but i can't understand how to do it in case of nesting inside elif statement? either it's possible or not? if yes, then how? and does it make sense to nest inside a elif statement?
**here's the code i want to convert into a single line code-**

```
m = ["b", "c"]
a = input()
if a=="a":
    x = "a"
elif a in m:
    if a=="b":
        x = "b"
    else:
        x = "c"
else:
    x = "unknown"
print(x)
```

please help me : (

Comment: In a single word: **don't**. Try this: in the Python interpreter, type `import this` and carefully read what prints out. This is called "The Zen of Python" and contains a lot of very useful suggestions of what "Pythonic" code should look like. One of the suggestions is *"Simple is better than complex."* Don't try to overly complicate things. Just because you *might* be able to combine a bunch of stuff into one line doesn't at all mean you *should*.

Comment: I believe you should do this! But only as a training exercise and you should do it yourself. After you succeeded, revert to the old version

Comment: I'm fully agreed to your answer. And notifying that i was just trying to know about it because of I've some codes of another's project and there he used this way to code. btw thank you man : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elif` and `else:` done by nesting a conditional expression into the `else` clause of the main conditional.

You should add lots of parentheses to ensure that the grouping of the conditionals is clear.

```
x = "a" if a == "a" else (("b" if a == "b" else "c") if a in m else "unknown")
```

I don't recommend writing like this, as it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = "a" if a == "a" else "b" if a == "b" else "c" if a == "c" else "unknown"
```

As mentioned earlier, this kind of expression is bad practice.
It is not readable there's simpler ways.

Comment: yes you are right that's the perfect way i got it

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your trivial solution glosses over much more complicated steps, but I wanted to point out an alternate way I often try to use to accomplish setting a value based on multiple potential conditions.

I recommend taking a look at how a dictionary might be used...

```
lookup = {
    "a": "A",
    "b": "B",
    "c": "C"
}

user_input = input("enter a single lowercase letter: ")
x = lookup.get(user_input, "unknown")
print(x)
```

I find it much easier to understand even as a golfy single line:

```
user_input = input("enter a single lowercase letter: ")
x = {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": "C"}.get(user_input, "unknown")
print(x)
```

Comment: yeah, i got it : )